# Showing last time a text box was changed

Tags: c#, textbox

I have text boxes that contain counts from a database. I want to be able to show the date and time that these text boxes were last changed. This what I have so far:

```
private void tbOnhand_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
label1.Content = "Last time changed was " + DateTime.Now;
}
```

This works but it shows the date of when the window opens. I want to be able to save the date and time and it not change until the text box is changed. Also, should there be a place for this in my database to store the time? Or is that not necessary. thanks

Comment: Erm ... you definitely are going to need a database, or a file or some persistent storage for this!

Comment: would there be a way to store it in a text file and look at the text file and pull the latest date? or any other way that wouldnt include changing the database?

Comment: That would be an extraordinarily ugly solution.  Change the database.

Comment: Do you want the time the text box was changed or the time when the user chose to save those changes?  If the data is being saved to the database then I don't see the point in saving the last modified date separate from the data

Comment: Yeah, I just want to see when the changes are saved.

Comment: You could store it in your App Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Text Change event fires whenever there is change in the content of text boxes, it better instead of showing date time on textbox change event you write this code after assigning the record count in the text box